# Loading Cross domain JSON file

Tags: json, wordpress, angularjs, cross-browser

I have a JSON file and I want to load it using Angular.JS.
Currently I am using below code and it is loading local JSON file data perfectly. But I want to load same JSON file but in different server. Can you please help me to load same JSON file from different server. I will really appreciate your help.

// JS

```
angular.module('list', []);

function ListCtrl($scope, $http) {
$http({
method: 'GET',
url: 'http://mywebsite/json_price_1.json?callback=angular.callbacks._1'
}).success(function(data) {
$scope.posts = data.posts; // response data
$scope.categories = [];
angular.forEach(data.posts, function(artist, index) {
  angular.forEach(artist.categories, function(album, index){
    $scope.categories.push(album);
  });
});
});
}
```

// HTML

```
<div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
<ul ng-repeat="artist in posts">
  <li>{{artist.slug}}</li>
</ul>
</div>

<h3>List of Albums</h3>

<div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
<ul ng-repeat="album in categories">
  <li>{{album.name}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

// JSON File

```
      {
"found": 22,
"posts": [
    {
        "ID": 85,
        "site_ID": 1,
        "author": {
            "ID": 1,
            "email": false,
            "name": "admin",
            "URL": "",
            "avatar_URL": "http:\/\/0.gravatar.com\/avatar\/aceb79084bb744b314d7af6485d80f72?s=96&d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%12345%3Fs%3D96&r=G",
            "profile_URL": "http:\/\/en.gravatar.com\/12345"
        },
        "date": "2014-06-06T15:00:12+00:00",
        "modified": "2014-06-06T15:00:12+00:00",
        "title": "Article22",
        "URL": "http:\/\/mywebsite.com\/tankers\/abc\/article22\/",
        "short_URL": "http:\/\/wp.me\/123-1n",
        "content": "<p>ar 16 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.<\/p>\n",
        "excerpt": "<p>ar 16 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex &hellip; <a href=\"http:\/\/mywebsite.com\/tankers\/abc\/article22\/\">Read More<\/a><\/p>\n",
        "slug": "article22",
        "guid": "http:\/\/mywebsite.com\/?p=85",
        "status": "publish",
        "sticky": false,
        "password": "",
        "parent": false,
        "type": "post",
        "comments_open": true,
        "pings_open": true,
        "likes_enabled": true,
        "sharing_enabled": true,
        "gplusauthorship_enabled": false,
        "comment_count": 0,
        "like_count": 0,
        "i_like": false,
        "is_reblogged": false,
        "is_following": false,
        "global_ID": "1234567890",
        "featured_image": "http:\/\/mywebsite.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/06\/article1.jpg",
        "format": "standard",
        "geo": false,
        "publicize_URLs": [

        ],
        "tags": {

        },
        "categories": {
            "Abc": {
                "name": "abc",
                "slug": "abc",
                "description": "",
                "post_count": 7,
                "meta": {
                    "links": {
                        "self": "https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1\/sites\/1111\/categories\/slug:aframax",
                        "help": "https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1\/sites\/1111\/categories\/slug:aframax\/help",
                        "site": "https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1\/sites\/1111"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make jsonp (cross domain requests) like this in angular...

```
var url = $http.jsonp('http://mywebsite/json_price_1.json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK');
```

then you iterate through the data in a success function

```
url.success(function(data) {
           //foreach statement
});
```

If you have a wordpress site - you should use this to allow cross domain ajax and to build the API: http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

Answer (score 1):

to do it xdomain (cross-domain) you will need to do a JSONP

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP jsonp general info

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp angularjs http.jsonp implementation

although if the named file on other server don't belong to you and you can't change it to work as jsonp then you are only left with backend solutions